# meaning of Farkas' Lemma

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Quoting from Jorge Nocedal's Numerical Optimization second edition, page 326 bottom to page 327, Farkas' Lemma

> Let the cone K be defined as in (12.45). Given any vector $g \in
>  \mathbb{R}^n$, we have either $g\in K$, or that there exists
>   $d\in\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying (12.46), but not both.

Also quoting from wikipedia, the geometric interpretation is

> Either
>
> 1. There exist coefficients $x_1,\dots, x_n \in \mathbb{R}, x_1, \ldots, x_n ≥ 0$,
>      such that $b = x_1 a_1 + \cdots + x_n a_n$.
> 2. There exists a vector $y \in\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $a_i · y ≥ 0$ for $i = 1,\ldots, n$ and $b · y < 0$.

Based on my understanding, does these simply means that the vector is either in the cone or it is outside the cone? If yes, then this lemma would be so plain in meaning

Answer (score 0):

That is true, but there is one additional information in the second alternative. Allow me to quote Wikipedia ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma)) as well:

> Farkas's lemma is a result in mathematics stating that a vector is
>   either in a given convex cone or that there exists a (hyper)plane
>   separating the vector from the cone—there are no other possibilities.

I mean the separating hyperplane surface
$$
H = \{ x \mid y^\top x = 0 \}
$$
The cone $C =\mbox{Cone}(\{ a_1, \ldots, a_n \})$ is above $H$, the vector $b$ below $H$.